# How to display woocommerce categories and products in a webpage and with different layout

Tags: templates, woocommerce

I have a different design for displaying product categories and its products and now don't know from where to start, how to do that dynamically?

I tried using the shortcode but it did not display anything.

I always worked with standart woocommerce styles and page so now need help.

Thanks.

Comment: I guess what you mean is you want to custom design category template and single product template. If this is correct then you will have to customize the woocommerce templates for those.

Comment: Yes you are right. How i can customise woocommerce template for avoiding upgrade issues @zipkundan?

Comment: You can copy the woo's template files into your active theme directory. Like `your-theme-folder/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Woocommerce templates are located in `plugins/woocommerce/templates/`. After copying the template files you can customize the copied files. This way even after updating the plugin version, your customization will retain.

Comment: Ah ok i see. I need to display product categories and its posts in separate webpage. How i can do that?

Comment: Welll, by "separate webpage" if you mean a non-woocommerce page, then you will need to write a custom query for that. Check [This](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) and [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155435/woocommerce-query-all-products-and-categories) link. May be it will help you.